# does the word "Puja" to denote a religious observance occur in scripture?

Tags: puja

Suniti Kumar Chatterji, the eminent linguist, has said that the concept of Puja is a distinctive contribution of the Dravidians.

It occurs in the Bhagavad Gita in a general sense

> Bhagavad Gita Chapter 2 Verse 4
>   भगवद् गीता अध्याय 2 श्लोक 4
>
> अर्जुन उवाच
>   कथं भीष्ममहं संख्ये द्रोणं च मधुसूदन।
>   इषुभिः प्रतियोत्स्यामि पूजार्हावरिसूदन।।2.4।।
>
> English Translation - Swami Gambirananda
>
> 2.4 Arjuna said O Madhusudana, O destroyer of enemies, how can I fight with arrows in battle against Bhisma and Drona who are worthy of adoration?

But where does it occur first to denote the formal act of worship as performed contemporarily?

Comment: Read my answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Shiva Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225561.html) has the etymology (निरुक्त​) of the word पूजा as 'पू: जायते' meaning 'that from which पुण्य is born for oneself'.

> 29-30. The word Pūjā is thus derived: Pūḥ means ‘the achievement of the fruits of enjoyment.’ By the rite one achieves the fruits. Jāyate means “is born.” Good ideas, knowledge etc. also are included in this. The word Pūjā is used in this sense amongst the people as well as in the sacred texts.

There are many types of पूजा described in those verses.

Answer (score 2):

The word **puja** is a Sanskrit word. It is mentioned in Rigveda.

- Rigved 8:17:12

> शाचिगो शाचि**पूज**नायं रणाय ते सुतः । आखण्डल प्र हूयसे॥१२॥
>
> Famed for thy radiance, **worshipped** well this juice is shed for thy delight Thou art invoked, Akhandala

Comment: A word occurring in Rig Veda is not precluded from being of Dravidian origin.

Comment: @SK you have clearly written**that it is not mentioned in the Vedas.** I was clearing you doubt

Comment: @SK dravidian culture is a part of Vedic culture

Comment: "dravidian culture is a part of Vedic culture"  @Sanatan Darshan - if you say that, we are in agreement.  I corrected my post with your information.  thank you.